# Sparrow spw= (Sparrow) new Bird(); what does the line mean?

Tags: java

where Sparrow and bird both are different classes and Sparrow class is an extended class of Bird class.

I just wanna see if i create an instance of Class Sparrow does it can implement the property of the  Bird object.

Comment: If `Sparrow` IS-A `Bird`, then you see all non-private fields and methods of `Bird` in `Sparrow` as well. Look up inheritance in Java.

Answer (score 1):

This line means the same thing as

```
throw new ClassCastException();
```

which is to say that it always fails and will never work.

To create a Sparrow, you must write `new Sparrow()` or `new SomeSubtypeOfSparrow()`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to do this. You are creating a generic Bird, and then casting it to a Sparrow. Since it is not a Sparrow (nor any subclass of Bird), it throws an exception when you try to do this.